# screenshot from webview

Tags: android, webview, webpage-screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of content of my WebView. I creare a bitmap and then create canvas from this bitmap, then I  call method drawPage(canvas) inside onPageFinished() (that is a callback from WebChromeClient), but inside onPageFinished() webView still hasn't loaded  content, so I see just black page at first, and then I see previous pages(because when I call it second time previous pages are loaded to webView). How could I deal with this problem? I can solve it using hadlers with some delay, but I think there should be better way to do this.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the problem, but are you asking how to trigger an event on a WebView loading a page? Could you create a WebView client and override the onPageCompleted()?

```
private WebViewClient viewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //here you can run your Bitmap creating code
        return true;
    }
}
YourWebView.setWebViewClient(viewClient);
```

Is this what your looking for?

Comment: If I take a screenshot inside onPageFinished() method I get a blank page at first time, when I load another page to the same webview and take a screenshot I get a previous page screen ( because webview still has previous page inside ). I'm looking for the moment when page that I loaded finally showed in web view.

Comment: I know you mentioned trying it on a delay, but your right, that seems wrong. Can I ask why you are trying to take a screenshot? That might not be the best way to achieve whatever you are trying to do.

Setting a "Loaded" Boolean to true in `onPageFinished()` and then checking if Loaded is true on the WebView's `onDraw()` method might do something, but just an idea.